# Web version of my Java desktop application

Tags: java, servlets

I developed a java desktop application to monitor which of the companies of my portfolio are paying dividends in the current month. Initially a calendar of the month is displayed. The days that I get a dividend are displayed in green and if a green day is clicked (all days are actually buttons), images of the companies that are paying that day are shown below. It is quite simple.

[image]

[image]

Now I would like to develope a web version of the application. I have read some documentation of Servlets and JSP but I am not sure if they are the right technologies to approach the problem. Can anyone recommend me what should I use (preferably in java) to develope a web application for my dividend calendar?

Answer (score 1):

## Vaadin

I would recommend [*Vaadin Flow*](https://vaadin.com/flow) as a great option for you to migrate to the web, especially considering that you have coded this up with Java.

The biggest advantage here is very minimal HTML/CSS/JavaScript writing as the Vaadin Flow framework automatically generates the web content needed to render your [form, fields, buttons, etc.](https://vaadin.com/components)

They also have some great starter projects for you to quickly understand the nuances.